# CakePHP 2 Shell Arguments help / example

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can't seem to find a simple concrete example of how to receive an argument on a CakePHP 2 shell script.

```
    class TestShell extends AppShell {
        public function argumentTest(){
            $parser = parent::getOptionParser();
            $parser->addArgument('testArgument', array('short' => 't','help' => 'The test argument'));
            var_dump($this->params);
        }
    }
```

I then try and call it:

- Console/cake TestShell argumentTest --t 45
- Console/cake TestShell argumentTest -t 45
- Console/cake TestShell argumentTest --testArgument 45
- Console/cake TestShell argumentTest -testArgument 45

with all of the above I get this as a response:

```
Usage:
cake lot_web_service [-h] [-v] [-q]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set up the arguments when the option parser is set up:

```
public function getOptionParser() {
    $parser = parent::getOptionParser();
    //configure parser
    return $parser;
}
```

This ensures that the options and arguments are set up prior to dispatching the call. Also, from what it looks like, you're wanting `addOption()` instead of `addArgument()`.

Comment: Thanks, worked like this:
`
public function getOptionParser() {
        $parser = parent::getOptionParser();
        $parser->addOption('testArgument', array('short' => 't','help' => 'The test argument'));
        return $parser;
    }
public function argumentTest(){
        var_dump($this->params);
    }
`

Comment: Thanks, so what worked was adding the getOptionParser then I added the call to addOption within the getOptionParser method. That made the option available to the $this->params property.

Comment: You can also use a boolean option like this: `$parser->addOption('debug', array('short' => 'd', 'boolean' => TRUE,'help' => 'Debug (run shorter procedure)'));`